# packaging a COM addin for deployment

Tags: c#, com, office-interop

Good Day All,

I am unfamiliar with the proper techniques for packaging a windows installer for my COM level addin (This is the higher level version which registers a COM server [implements the ID2Extesibility interface] and can be distributed to all office products at once [word, excel, etc]). I am using VS2010 and am attempting to get the addin to work on a customer's computer. I believe that I have figured out the problem is within the COM registration itself. It seems that the installer has decided to reference my development binary and not the installed location. How can i change this value in the installer?

Basically it is writing
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{MYclassID}\InprocServer32\{VER}\CodeBase` as `"C:\MyVS10Install\MyProj\Debug\MyProjDLL.dll"`

How do i change this to:

`c:\Program Files\My Install Path\MyProjDLL.dll`

??

Any help would be great, its impossible to find any information on this because I probably don't know what I'm looking for.

EDIT:

I am thinking it's the registration portion, because the addin works perfectly in my computer, but doesn't install on the customer's

Comment: I have tried changing the value in "Primary Output from..."->properties->Register to vsdrpCOMRelativePath and vsdrpCOM

Comment: So, is this reg key written by an installer, or regsrvr/regasm? If its the installer's responsibility to write the key to the machine, then try using [INSTALLDIR]\My Install Path\MyProjDLL.dll and Windows Installer should map this out as long as INSTALLDIR is set appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that the installer has decided to reference my development
>   binary and not the installed location. How can i change this value in
>   the installer?

If you believe it is the Installer responsible for the problem, check that CodeBase is not hardcoded to point to `C:\MyVS10Install`. You should be able to see this in the Registry table of the msi database

If it is hardcoded to point there, then try using `[INSTALLDIR]\My Install Path\MyProjDLL.dll` as the value